# Наложение цвета на цвет | CSS

Tags: css

Есть блок, который изначально имеет цвет `rgba(34, 33, 35, 0.8)`, на него нужно наложить цвет `rgba(255, 185, 67, 0.2)`, чтобы получилось так, как на картинке:

[image: наложение цветов]

Я пробовал способ:

```css
.container {
  background-image: url('image.jpg');
  background-color: ;
  background-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

Но в итоге получился эффект не тот, что нужен.

Comment: синтаксис ведь позволяет перечислить друг за другом через запятую несколько фонов

Comment: Вы про это?
background: rgba(34, 33, 35, 0.8), rgba(255, 185, 67, 0.2);
Если да, то в итоге эффект всё равно оказался не тем, что нужен.

Comment: у вас на картинке один блок в другом расположен. у каждого свой фон.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в ваших примерах изображения содержится не один блок с разными фонами, а два блока каждый со своим фоном.

```css
body {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/eWtfMME.png) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.wrapper {
  background: rgba(34, 33, 35, 0.8);
  border-radius: 1rem;
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 4rem;
  position: relative;
  
}
.inner {
  background: rgba(255, 185, 67, 0.2);
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:50%;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: -2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">
</div>
```

Comment: Да, я использовал этот способ до этого и он оказался верным, но на тот момент я проверял его на белом фоне, из-за чего подумал, что эффект не тот, что нужен, сейчас проверил в другой обстановке и понял, что это то, что мне нужно, спасибо за помощь!